# How to get mouse position and buffer?

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, buffer

How do I get the mouse position. I have tried:

```
int mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
    int mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
```

But that does it for the whole screen. Anyway to do it relative to the JPanel/JFrame

If I'm only using Graphics JFrame and JPanel that is being repainted every millisecond, should I have buffers? Or will it be fine?

Comment: **Thanks I need help take your time for your answer. It will pay off**

Comment: **+ 1 downvote. Im guessing not being clear vauge question and un needed data?**

Comment: Not your down-voter, but consider making less comments and more improvement to the question. Try to streamline it so we can see just what specifically your problem/question is. I've been reading it a few times and have yet to fully understand it.

Comment: Okay I think I tried to ask to many questions and ramble on ill edit a bit.

Comment: As a minor side recommendation, consider renaming your classes since Java core already has both a Frame and Panel class, and the name clash can be confusing for some (such as me).

Comment: Thanks ill edit and thanks Hovercraft Eels.

Comment: I will be taking on the advice given. I am new and I am a bit tired so grammer mistakes will be found.

Comment: please stick to one question per post - not 4. That's not really answerable as such. If you edit it, we can reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I add a mouseAcionEvent only to the frame so it gets X() and Y() of mouse but only in frame?

Use a `MouseListener` instead of `MouseInfo`.  `MouseListener` will trigger events which are contextual to the component which raised them, which means you won't need to translate the events into the component space as the event will already be converted to within the component context.

See [How to write a mouse listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details

> How should I update my game rePaint() every millisecond or another way?

Use a `javax.swing.Timer`...

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details...

> Should I use buffers?

That will depend.  Swing components are already double buffered, but if you use a more complex timing mechanism (AKA game loop), you might find it useful, even to roll your own.

I, personally, would start simple

> How can I improve the way I thought out my code in the first place? Is it right having 10 loops or only all in 1 to reduce lag ect.

There are probably lots of things, but start with broader idea...

- Breakdown entities to their own responsibilities, for example, the player should know where it is and how it should be painted.  It could even know how it's suppose to move based on the current state of the game.  This way you could create any number of entities, all with there own set of rules which are isolated and easily updated.
- Devise a controller mechanism which is responsible for taking in keyboard and mouse events and simply updating the current state of the game model.  That is, rather than going  "the user pressed the 'left' key, move player to the left", it would simply raise a flag in the game model that the "left" state has been triggered (or untriggered) and the engine would, on the next update loop, ensure that each entity knew about the change
- Don't use magic or hard coded numbers, instead provide some kind of ability to scale the scene.  For example, you could decide what is shown on the screen based on the size of the window...

Comment: Good enough.  Thanks!